# Developing a request and response system

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, design-patterns

An example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328075.aspx

I am looking to design a request and response system for a project. The request and responses are both classes.

I don't use interfaces because I do use Command by its self.

Example of use:

```
dim result as Response = ExecuteCommand(of Response)(new Read())

dim result as DiffResponse = ExecuteCommand(of DiffResponse)(new Read())
```

Example of design:

```
Class Command
    Private buffer as new List(of byte)

    Sub New(byval command As byte)
        buffer.add(command);
    End Sub

    Overrideable get_request() As byte()
        Return buffer.toarray
    End Function
End Class

Class Read
    Inherits Command

    Sub New()
        MyBase.New(&h01)
    End Sub
End Class

Class Response
    Private buffer As New List(Of Byte)

    Sub New(ByVal data() As Byte)
    {
       buffer.addrange(data)
    }
End Class
```

Now I want to be able to have multiple types of Response so example:

```
Class DiffResponse
    Inherits Response

    Sub New(data As Bytes())
        MyBase.new(data)
        ' Custom processing
    End Sub
End Class
```

The DiffResponse class might have custom getter functions and variables.

Presently I do something like this:

```
Public Function ExecuteCommand(Of response)(ByVal command As Command) As response
    Return GetType(response).GetConstructor(New Type() {GetType(Byte())}).Invoke(New Object() {Me.WritePacket(command.get_request)})
End Function
```

Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: Not clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you give a concrete example of how you might use these classes?

Comment: dim result as DiffResponse = ExecuteCommand(of DiffResponse)(new Command(&h1));

Comment: Can a Command return any possible response? e.g. Dim result as AnotherResponse = ExecuteCommand(of AnotherResponse)(new Command(&h1)); Or is the response class tied to the command somehow?

Comment: no, command is a packet constructor of forms. A custom request could build a completely different packet from another. Response classes will parse the data out. I am open to any methods.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Your design doesn't 'feel' right but I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps you could contact me via skype or something? I would like to pick your brain.

Comment: Can we talk on an instant messenger? Perhaps you can help guide me...This design presently works just feel its off